# Are expansion civs/natural wonders more likely?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I've played several games of Civ 5 with the Gods and Kings expansion, and it seems like every game has involved a similar cast of characters (Austria, Sweden, Byzantium) as well as many of the new natural wonders (the ones that give faith).

This was interesting to see the new content, but now it is getting a bit repetitive.  Am I correct in thinking that expansion content is more likely to appear than non-expansion content?  Is there some way to modify this so that everything is equally likely?

Comment: Confirmation bias seems likely

Comment: ive had nothing like that happen.

Comment: @Raven That's certainly possible, I don't have the largest sample size, it just seemed pretty unlikely that I kept seeing the same things each game.

Comment: I haven't done any tests or anything, but it seems to me like I am getting more of the expansion civs in the game as well. I have not noticed a notable pattern in the wonders. Then again, there are A LOT of new civs, so it is pretty likely you would get at least one in a 4-6 player game.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late to answer this with regards to the G+K expansion, but I am not experiencing any phenomenon like this with the recent Brave New World expansion. Civs and natural wonders have appeared with the same frequency as should be expected given an equal chance of any civ appearing.

Answer (score 0):

The civilizations seem to go the direction of religious domination every game if they cannot bully you through any other means, so naturally civilizations will make stuff with faith more, which are mostly expansion content. I never encountered long and consecutive consistencies in enemy civilizations chosen by AI though...

Comment: The question is about which civilizations/natural wonders are randomly chosen as opponents, not what they do once the game starts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've had the same experience. The expansion content appears more in the first few games, but after playing several games through a period of around 2 months, the expansion content seems to be getting lesser, and civs and natural wonders more randomized.